# Is there any Autocad mobile SDK to show and edit dwg files?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'd like to show and edit dwg files in my iOS and Android app. Is there any Autocad mobile SDK to use? I didn't find in autocad website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Forge perspective, there is no native mobile component for manipulating DWG files. You *could* however achieve a "kind-of editing experience" by collecting a set of updates your user wants to apply to their DWGs, and then apply the updates in the cloud, leveraging the [Forge Design Automation service for AutoCAD](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/autocad).